Иерархия прав доступа в Windows 11
У меня есть целый список расширений в Chrome, и мне нужно одно из них сделать так, чтобы я не мог его изменять, то есть один раз внес первоначальные настройки и всё!
Где-то в интернете я нашел способ что можно попробовать через права доступа к файлам (файлам расширений).
А именно:

найти пусть: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions, (в Extensions находятся все папки расширений chrome)
затем зайти в свойства конкретного расширения в моем случае "khncfooichmfjbepaaaebmommgaepoid" (это его идентификатор).
Далее безопасность\изменить\выбрать user.

И вот здесь, у меня возникает та проблема с наследованием-иерархией, когда я хочу поставить галочки "изменение" и "запись" в столбце "запретить", то они не ставятся по отдельности, все галочки проставляются считая с низу до галочки "изменение", которую я хочу запретить. (Я еще картинку отправил).
Я попробовал исправить ситуацию

зайдя также в свойства\безопасность\дополнительно, затем прожать "отключение наследование"

но перед тем как отключить, вышло уведомление "блокировать наследование" точнее выбор, (тоже отправил картинку). Я выбрал первое 'преобразовать" хотя не полностью осознавая что это значит. (Конечно в процесса всего я не забывал нажимать "применить" и только после "ок")

затем решил перезагрузить Ноутбук. К сожалению не сработало
я решил тогда второй выбрать "удаление" после повторил все тоже самое но опять не сработало.
Затем я узнал что можно в "дополнительно" тоже ставить галочки а именно выбрать субъект: User\изменить и появляться галочки но и здесь тоже наследование работает, то есть не получается отдельно галочки ставить.


Сделать надо чтобы галочки были так сказать независимыми что ли, то
есть чтобы я мог только те галочки выбирать которые мне нужны.




Типичный пример попытки переноса проблем с человеческим фактором в сферу "большого брата" или "большой красной кнопки". Ковыряния в этих каталогах таких образом могут породить такие "эффекты", что потребуется двадцать следователей для выяснения.
Я лично сам когда-то нажимал на эти галочки, но мне надо было просто сбросить права на файлы перед удалением. Та ещё морока была. К счастью, это всё уже давно позади и необходимость в этом не встречается.

Я не совсем вас понял, вы можете мне помочь ?

Чем? Долбите эти птички, может получится. Из Ваших объяснений понять ничего невозможно. Я предупредил просто и попробую ещё раз - возможно, Вы пытаетесь решить проблему не с той стороны. Что-то мне подсказывает, что если разобраться с "проблемой" сначала, то она вовсе и не проблема, а так называемый "человеческий фактор". Как системщик, я часто сталкиваюсь с проблемами, создаваемыми пользователями, но я решаю их просто и без "красных кнопок". Я не хочу здесь просто гадать, что именно порождает "проблему", но скорее всего она тривиальна.

В конце концов удалить Ваше "заблокированное" расширение и установить его опять не бог весть какая проблема. Магазин расширений написан для полных компьютерных нулей, ничего сложного, нужно знать только название расширения. И что?

Я просто хочу сделать так, чтобы я не мог изменять определенные расширения в Google Chrome, только единожды задать первоначальные настройки и все.  я не "системщик" и не профессионал в этой области, поэтому и пушу в "Stackoverflow", если бы я был как вы то и не писал бы вовсе. Я попытался максимально обширно объяснить что мне нужно выше, добавив скриншоты. Если у вас есть реальная помощь или хотя бы варианты как можно решить проблему с ТОЙ стороны, то буду благодарен.

До тех пор, пока Вы не объясните толком что именно за проблема, никаких решений не увидите. Как это, запретить самому себе менять настройки? Что такое "изменять определенные расширения"? На каком это языке? На ИТ? ТАК НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ ИХ! На Ваших скриншотах нет ни одной внятной и понятной информации, потому что процесс изменения атрибутов многоступенчатый, надо видеть всё и по порядку. И я ещё раз пытаюсь посоветовать - не ковыряйтесь в этом в этих каталогах, результат может быть очень непредсказуемым. Всё там намного проще.

"...Я где-то читал, что надо запретить доступ, я хочу чтоб определённые расширения..." - это не постановка задачи. Где читали? Что читали? Что за расширение? Почему его надо блокировать самому себе? Почему нельзя просто сказать самому себе: "НЕТРОЖЬ! НИЗЗЯ!"? Почему нельзя ис пользовать несколько аккаунтов, в одном из которых этого расширения просто нет в браузере? Почему над клещами вытягивать из Вас подробное описание проблемы? :-))))

При всем уважении к вашему профессионализму, надо было вам так сразу и сказать! ... Попробую более детально объяснить проблему: Я очень много провожу времени за ютуб, смотрю много ненужного контента, откровенно говоря мусор, что сильно мешает учебе! А силы воли увы не хватает. Я узнал что есть расширения для Google Chrome которые устанавливаются через chromewebstore.google.com и некоторые из них позволяют ограничивать функциональность ютуба например: убрать ленту рекомендуемых видео, все подписки, Shorts и так далее. Одно из таких расширений называется DF Tube (Distraction Free for YouTube™)

Я скачал это расширение и оно прекрасно работает, но главный минус в том что я в любой момент можно просто зайти в это расширение (его настройки) и убрать то что ограничивает функциональность YouTube. То есть я могу управлять этим расширением, поэтому мне надо как то найти способ чтобы у меня не было доступа к этому расширению, точнее чтобы оно работало конечно же, но я не мог бы заходить в его настройки. Тогда при всем желании я бы не смог смотреть мусор в YouTube). Я написал это в ChatGPT и мне он предложил множество вариантов решения одно из них и было то что я писал выше.

Для болей точности я вставлю то что он мне написал,  "1. Заблокировать доступ к изменениям настроек через права доступа к файлам. Для этого можно изменить права доступа к файлам расширения на компьютере: Найти папку расширения: Для Google Chrome: Расширения находятся
C:\Users[Имя пользователя]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions (как я писал выше у меня путь немного другой оказался) В папке Extensions будут папки с длинными названиями — это идентификаторы установленных расширений. Найди ту, которая относится к (расширению который я написал выше).

Изменить права доступа: Щёлкни правой кнопкой по папке соответствующего расширения. Выбери Свойства > вкладка Безопасность. Нажми Изменить и: Для своей учётной записи сними галочку с "права записи" и "изменения". Оставь только Чтение. Это сделает невозможным изменение файлов расширения, включая настройки. Проверить: После изменения прав доступа попробуй изменить настройки в интерфейсе расширения. Браузер не сможет записывать изменения." Вот по этой инструкции я следовал, Но у меня возникла проблема в том что эти галочки не ставятся по отдельности, То что я писал в самом начале.

В рекомендациях написано что нежелательно писать развернутые комментарии, и в комментариях и оказывается я не могу добавлять картинки, может вы дадите свою почту чтобы я мог вам отправить все скриншоты, или как это можно здесь сделать? если основываясь на всем тексте что я написал выше, можно теперь найти способ решение моей ситуации ?

Что еще в тексте надо написать чтобы было подробное описание проблемы я уже не представляю честно), написал абсолютно все и даже больше наверно. Если же чего то не хватает напишите конкретно чего.

Черещ групповые политики пробовали? https://remontka.pro/block-extensions-install-google-chrome/ (сторонний сайт с рекламой, осторожнее)
